# oracle stored proc returning datasets based on count

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, if-statement, count

We currently have a stored proc that needs to do the following:
If Query1 returns any results open a sys_refcursor cursor for that and return it back
else
open a cursor for Query2

Currently we are doing a count(*) on the from and where clauses of Query1 and use the count in a if-else stmt.  However, this causes query1 to be executed twice.  Is there a way to optimize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the cursor for query1 & perform the real query. Wrap it in a BEGIN .. END block & catch the no data found exception.

```
BEGIN

-- query1 code

-- return data

EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   NULL;

BEGIN
-- query2 code

-- return data

END;
```

The query2 code will get run when there's no data returned by query1.

Answer (score 0):

I like Phil's answer as well, but another option is to use same logic you're using, but change count query to use a rownum stopkey, like:

```
select count(1)
into v_cnt
from some_table
where some_field like 'ABC%'
and rownum <= 1;
```

The rownum can allow Oracle to stop counting once it gets a hit (meaning there are 1 or more rows returning from the query).  Can make a big difference depending on the data and query of course.